# How to increase column values?

Tags: openoffice-calc

How to increase column values from:

```
1 | 1 | 7.317073
2 | 1 | 14.634146
3 | 1 | 24.390244
4 | 2 | 7.317073
5 | 2 | 14.634146
6 | 2 | 24.390244
```

To:

```
1 | 1 | 7.317073
2 | 1 | 14.634146
3 | 1 | 24.390244
4 | 2 | 7.317073
5 | 2 | 14.634146
6 | 2 | 24.390244
7 | 3 | 7.317073
8 | 3 | 14.634146
9 | 3 | 24.390244
10 | 4 | 7.317073
11 | 4 | 14.634146
12 | 4 | 24.390244
```

I'm using Open Office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the top left corner is A1, set the fourth row such:

A4: `=A3+1`

B4: `=roundup(A4/3)`

C4 `=C1`

And pull them up to row 12

Comment: Ha! Clever! But =roundup(A4/3) dont work because it throw #NAME?

Answer (score 0):

For ColumnA simply selecting the first three rows, grabbing the fill handle (black square at the bottom right of the range) and dragging down to suit should be sufficient.

An alternative here to ROUNDUP is, in B1 and copied down:

```
=INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1
```

For ColumnC as for ColumnA but with <kbd>Crl</kbd> depressed.